# How can I create a menu for an iPhone application that utilizes both a tabbed view mode and a standard UI mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm looking to create an application with a menu that loads a tabbed application, but can also load another separate view application. I'm kind of confused how you could get a standard view to load as a menu and then have one of your menu button IBaction's call up a whole other "application," for lack of a better word.

To make things more clear, I want to do this:

1. Load menu
2. If user pushes the option for the tabbed app, that app opens
3. If users pushes the option for the single view app, it opens

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the term application to mean a `ViewController`. If that is the case, you can use the initial view controller and call `presentModalViewController` to show the second ViewControllers. Some pseudocode in your "Menu" ViewController:

```
- (IBAction) showTabbedSection
{
    YourTabbedVC *tabVC = [[[YourTabbedVC alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:tabVC animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction) showSomeOtherSection
{
    SomeOtherVC *otherVC = [[[SomeOtherVC alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:otherVC animated:NO];
}
```

Those methods would be the `IBAction` handlers hooked up to the controls in your "Menu."

Comment: Thanks! That makes complete sense.